# Iterative Methods

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Does anyone have an example of a linear system that has a single solution but can not be solved by the Jacobi method or Gauss Seidel method

Comment: think about what kind of matrix would the Gauss Seidel or the Jacobi fail on?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with starting point at $(1,1)$

$$x=11-y\\y=10x$$

$$(1,1) \to (10,100) \to (-89, -890)\to (100,1000)\to (-989, -9890),...$$
The actual solution is $(1,10)$